# How to convert key value text to json arrya format python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a use case where we have text file like key value format .
The file is not any of the fixed format but created like key value .

We need to create JSON out of that file .

I am able to create JSON but when text format has array like structure it creates just Key value json not the array json structure .

This is my Input .

```
[DOCUMENT]
Headline=This is Headline
MainLanguage=EN
DocType.MxpCode=1000
Subject[0].MxpCode=BUSNES
Subject[1].MxpCode=CONS
Subject[2].MxpCode=ECOF
Author[0].MxpCode=6VL6
Industry[0].CtbCode=53
Industry[1].CtbCode=5340
Industry[2].CtbCode=534030
Industry[3].CtbCode=53403050
Symbol[0].Name=EXPE.OQ
Symbol[1].Name=ABNB.OQ
WorldReg[0].CtbCode=G4
Country[0].CtbCode=G26
Country[1].CtbCode=G2V
[ENDOFFILE]
```

Exiting code to create json is below

```
with open("file1.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
data = {}
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split('=')
    if len(parts) == 2:
        data[parts[0].strip()] = parts[1].strip()
print(json.dumps(data, indent='  '))
```

The current output is below

```
{
  "Headline": "This is Headline",
  "MainLanguage": "EN",
  "DocType.MxpCode": "1000",
  "Subject[0].MxpCode": "BUSNES",
  "Subject[1].MxpCode": "CONS",
  "Subject[2].MxpCode": "ECOF",
  "Author[0].MxpCode": "6VL6",
  "Industry[0].CtbCode": "53",
  "Industry[1].CtbCode": "5340",
  "Industry[2].CtbCode": "534030",
  "Industry[3].CtbCode": "53403050",
  "Symbol[0].Name": "EXPE.OQ",
  "Symbol[1].Name": "ABNB.OQ",
  "WorldReg[0].CtbCode": "G4",
  "Country[0].CtbCode": "G26",
  "Country[1].CtbCode": "G2V"
}
```

**Expected out is is something like below**

For the Subject key and like wise for others also

```
{
  "subject": [
    {
      "mxcode": 123
    },
    {
      "mxcode": 123
    },
    {
      "mxcode": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

Like wise for Industry and Symbol and Country.

so the idea is when we have position in the text file it should be treated as array in the json output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is creating a dictionary, which is outputted to a JSON array.

You could condense this code to your needs.

```
import json
import re as regex
from collections import defaultdict

keys = set()
data  = defaultdict(dict)

elements = [element.strip().split('=') for element in open("sample_file.text")]
for element in elements:
    main_topic = ''.join([regex.split('\[', item)[0] for item in element if '[' in item]).lower()
    sub_topic = ''.join([regex.split('\.', item)[1] for item in element if '[' in item and len(element) == 2]).lower()
    if main_topic and main_topic in keys and sub_topic:
       data[main_topic][sub_topic].append(element[1].strip())
    elif main_topic and main_topic not in keys and sub_topic:
        keys.add(main_topic)
        data[main_topic][sub_topic] = [element[1].strip()]
    elif not main_topic and main_topic not in keys:
        if ']' not in element[0]:
            main_topic = element[0].split('.')[0].lower()
            if '.' not in element[0]:
                data[main_topic] = element[1].lower().strip()
            elif '.' in element[0]:
                sub_topic = element[0].split('.')[1].lower()
                data[main_topic][sub_topic] = [element[1].strip()]

print(json.dumps(data, indent='  '))
```

JSON Output:

```
{
  "headline": "This is Headline",
  "mainlanguage": "EN",
  "doctype": {
    "mxpcode": [
      "1000"
    ]
  },
  "subject": {
    "mxpcode": [
      "BUSNES",
      "CONS",
      "ECOF"
    ]
  },
  "author": {
    "mxpcode": [
      "6VL6"
    ]
  },
  "industry": {
    "ctbcode": [
      "53",
      "5340",
      "534030",
      "53403050"
    ]
  },
  "symbol": {
    "name": [
      "EXPE.OQ",
      "ABNB.OQ"
    ]
  },
  "worldreg": {
    "ctbcode": [
      "G4"
    ]
  },
  "country": {
    "ctbcode": [
      "G26",
      "G2V"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error :    data[main_topic][sub_topic] = [element[1].strip()]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @AtharvThakur I just ran the code again with no errors.  What does you input file look like?  Also which line threw the error?

Comment: My Input same that i have posted in question ..Not the json  one but key value one ..Error is this `line 11, in <listcomp>
    sub_topic = ''.join([regex.split('\.', item)[1] for item in element if '[' in item]).lower()
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I found the problem.  I didn't have *[DOCUMENT]* or *[ENDOFFILE]* in my dataset.  I corrected that and the code. LMK if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

```html
import re
import json


with open("file.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
data = {}
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split('=')
    if len(parts) == 2:
        key, value = parts[0].strip(), parts[1].strip()
        # Use regex to check if key has position in its name
        match = re.match(r'^(\w+)\[(\d+)\]\.(\w+)$', key)
        if match:
            array_key, index, obj_key = match.groups()
            # Create array of objects for the given key
            if array_key not in data:
                data[array_key] = []
            # Create new object or update existing object at the given index
            if len(data[array_key]) <= int(index):
                data[array_key].append({obj_key: value})
            else:
                data[array_key][int(index)][obj_key] = value
        else:
            data[key] = value
# Convert dictionary to JSON with proper indentation
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Actually  the code looks like the previous answer but I followed more your expected output with every subject industry etc to be set of dictionaries.

```html
{
  "Headline": "This is Headline",
  "MainLanguage": "EN",
  "DocType.MxpCode": "1000",
  "Subject": [
    {
      "MxpCode": "BUSNES"
    },
    {
      "MxpCode": "CONS"
    },
    {
      "MxpCode": "ECOF"
    }
  ],
  "Author": [
    {
      "MxpCode": "6VL6"
    }
  ],
  "Industry": [
    {
      "CtbCode": "53"
    },
    {
      "CtbCode": "5340"
    },
    {
      "CtbCode": "534030"
    },
    {
      "CtbCode": "53403050"
    }
  ],
  "Symbol": [
    {
      "Name": "EXPE.OQ"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ABNB.OQ"
    }
  ],
  "WorldReg": [
    {
      "CtbCode": "G4"
    }
  ],
  "Country": [
    {
      "CtbCode": "G26"
    },
    {
      "CtbCode": "G2V"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It doe notprint anything for me exact code i ran

Comment: What python did you run and what system? I pasted the result of the code. 
@AtharvThakur 
because I pasted the code that my run created. I used 3.10 & 3.11 in win10

Answer (score 0):

Use one more loop as it is nested. Use for loop from where subject starts. try it that way.